# Textbox control can't accept different data types of input

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

I would like to search student by using **Student ID** OR **Student Name**. So I wrote my SELECT Statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [student] WHERE ([S_FName] LIKE '%' + @S_FName + '%') OR (SID =@SID)
```

However, both parameters `@S_FName` & `@SID` are sharing the same textbox control to let users search student. S_FName is `varchar(50)` and SID is `int`

I can't really search student by using student name or student ID by using single textbox. I keep getting the error:
`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'student1' to data type int.]`

Comment: Yes you can, just use a simple if/else statement with a different select statement in each, depending on what was entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same search term, entered by the user, for both comparisons.
For the `INT`, convert it to a string first. 
Another choice would be to convert the search term to an `INT`, but then you'd have to have special handling for non-numeric values.

```
create table Student 
  ( StudentID int,
    StudentName nvarchar(80) )

insert into Student ( StudentID, StudentName ) values
( 10123, 'Archimedes' ),
( 74701, 'Beatrice'   ),
( 84448, 'Casandra'   ),
( 99599, 'Archibald'  )

declare @Search nvarchar(80)

set @Search = 'Arch'

select * from Student 
where ( StudentName like '%' + @Search + '%' )
or ( cast(StudentID as nvarchar(20)) = @Search )

set @Search = '74701'

select * from Student 
where ( StudentName like '%' + @Search + '%' )
or ( cast(StudentID as nvarchar(20)) = @Search )
```

If you have SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use `Try_Convert` to simplify.

```
select * from Student 
where ( StudentName like N'%' + @Search + N'%' )
or ( StudentID = Try_Convert(int,@Search) )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass one parameter, because Textbox is same
and you must convert id to varchar so that type of id and fname is equal
so you can Follow the code below

```
    SELECT        [S_FName], SID, CAST(SID AS 
    varchar(50)) + '-' + S_FName AS S_FName_ID
    FROM            Coding_view
    WHERE        (CAST(SID AS varchar(50)) + '-' + S_FName LIKE 
    N'%Behmagham%')
```

good luck